# Need to recompile assets in Rails in case of change. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application. Here is the part of the content of development.rb

```
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compress = false
```

When I change any `js` file, I have to call  `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` to see the changes. I wonder why? How do I get rid of that? I want just to save `javascript` file and not to do any extra work.

P.S. It's not only about javascript files. Even when I change a haml file, I also have to call `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile`.

Comment: app/javascript/assets

Comment: Don't run precompile - delete the public/assets folder

Comment: yes, it's app/assets/javascripts actually.

Comment: @FrederickCheung, it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time you run the `assets:precompile` Rails place compiled assets into `public/assets`. The issue is that the assets pipeline will always serve an asset from the `public` directory if it founds it here. Otherwise it will search assets in the `app/assets` directory which is the appropriate location for assets in development.

You're not supposed to precompile assets in your development environment, assets precompilation is for production environments. If you want to do it periodically, for example to check compiled/minified assets, don't forget to remove the `public/assets` directory once you're done.

Comment: I uploaded this project to heroku (git add ., git commit -m, etc) but the source code of javascript files are not changed. config.assets.compile = false

Comment: Heroku is supposed to compile assets at deployment-time if they're not present : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 6):

Try removing public/assets directory. From your app's directory:

```
rm -rf public/assets
```

Comment: It didn't help. Besides, it appears again.

Comment: In your config/development.rb, do you have a line that says,'config.assets.compile = true'? If so, either change to 'false' or comment it out. Then remove the public/assets folder again.